# Creating a Function that works for 2 models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models which need an identical function. I'd like to learn how to make this DRY the right rails way...

For both models I have:

```
before_save :assign_uuid
```

Which in each model has:

```
  def assign_uuid
    if self.uuid.nil?
      self.uuid = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(32)
    end
  end
```

Since, assign_uuid lives in both models, Where is the one place I should place this func? Also, in the models, where it say's before_save. How do I call the assign_uuid in the location it is located?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no Ruby expert, so I'm not sure if this is frowned upon or not, but if I were you, I'd chuck it in a file in *lib/* and whack it straight on ActiveRecord::Base with **class_eval.**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def assign_uuid
    if self.uuid.nil?
      self.uuid = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(32)
    end
  end 
end
```

That way, it's available for all your models. Either that, or create a miscellaneous model helpers file and include the module into the models you'd like.

```
# lib/misc_model_helpers.rb
module MiscModelHelpers
  def assign_uuid
    if self.uuid.nil?
      self.uuid = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(32)
    end
  end 
end

# models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MiscModelHelpers
  before_save :assign_uuid
end
```

Again, I'm really not 100% on the most rubyish way of doing this. It's probably something completely different. These are just two ways that work for me!

Comment: I think both are acceptable, and it depends on the case. If you need to add functionality to ALL your models, re-open ActiveRecord::Base. On the other hand, including a module is also explicit and is clearer to comprehend imho.

Answer (score 1):

In your `lib` folder, add a file `uuid_lib.rb`, and write

```
module UuidLib

  def assign_uuid
    if self.uuid.nil?
      self.uuid = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(32)
    end
  end
end
```

and inside your model write

```
include UuidLib

before_save :assign_uuid
```

An example article explaining modules and mixins in more detail can be found [here](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/).

Answer (score -1):

You should add this as a module and mix it into your models, that is the Ruby way to do what you are after.

Comment: Add it as a module where? Mix in my models how?